How to create a console process with a given window size and position?
I am using startup information to specify the size and position of a window I wish to open, but WinApi uses instead the default values for those parameters.
Here is a (Component Pascal) call to create a console process using WinApi:
res:= WinApi.CreateProcessW (NIL, lpCommandLine, NIL, NIL, 0, 
    WinApi.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 0, NIL, startupInfo, processInfo);

Where lpCommandLine is  "cmd /K " + some command.
Previously, I have prepared starupInfo as follows:
startupInfo.cb:= SIZE(WinApi.STARTUPINFOW);
startupInfo.dwFlags:= WinApi.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW +
    WinApi.STARTF_USESIZE + WinApi.STARTF_USEPOSITION;  (* set union *)
startupInfo.dwXSize:= 200; startupInfo.dwYSize:= 100;
startupInfo.dwX:= 100; startupInfo.dwY:= 10;
startupInfo.lpTitle:= "Corcel"

Everything works, except that it ignores the size and position requested for the window. What is wrong in there?

Specifying a size and position is just a hint, not a guarantee. The target app is under no obligation to use them.

"cmd /K " not need do this. execute some command direct without cmd

The reason I added "cmd /k" is because I am using output redirection in that app.

If you want to do it. Please use SetConsoleWindowInfo then SetConsoleScreenBufferSize. The specified window rectangle extends cannot beyond the boundaries of the console screen buffer.

I am using output redirection in that app and so what ? how cmd here related ? absolute wrong use this

@René you don't need to run cmd to perform redirection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output
